# PHP not sending outbound mail

Tags: php, sendmail

I'm using the sendmail package and php, When I try to use the mail function in PHP it returns true but nothing is sent.

php config

```
; For Unix only.  You may supply arguments as well (default: "sendmail -t -i").
; http://php.net/sendmail-path
sendmail_path =/usr/sbin/sendmail -t -i
```

php file

```
error_reporting(E_ALL|E_STRICT);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
trace(mail('jamie@domain.tld','Testing','test.'));
```

the mailer log is displaying this

```
mail() on [/var/www/misc/mail.php:5]: To: jamie@domain.tld -- Headers:
```

Running sendmail through the CLI as this:

```
echo -e "To: jamie@domain.tld\nSubject: Test\nTest\n" | sendmail -bm -t -v
```

Returns "Sender ok", "Recipient ok"

Anyone know of anything which could be causing php to not send the email?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

PHP has nothing to do with mail delivery. Its job begins and ends with handing the email off to the specified SMTP agent/server. If `mail()` does not return a boolean FALSE, then PHP's job has succeeded and it's out of the picture.

Check your SMTP server's logs to see what happens to the email after the handoff is completed. It's quite likely the mail is being rejected/greylisted/spamfiltered into oblivion, because PHP's `mail()` truly blows.

Consider switching to either [Swiftmailer](http://swiftmailer.org) or [PHPMailer](http://phpmailer.worxware.com), both of which offer far better diagnostics of the PHP<->SMTP interactions than mail() ever will.

Testing manually from the command line means little: your shell environment is very different from the in-webserver environment that your script is likely executing in - apples and oranges.

Comment: I would echo the comment here that relying on mail() is really a bad idea for any application where you do not control and understand how to configure the entire server environment.  I prefer to use a service like SendGrid, Amazon SES (not good for marketing email), or similar where you simply send mail via an API call.  Many of these services have a free tier you can operate on if you are just sending low volume email in a testing environment.

Answer (score 1):

This can be misleading. PHP will return true because, as far as *its* concerned, it has done its part. But it has no guarantee that the SMTP server will honour the request.

When this happened to me once, it turned out my host had implemented a new stipulation that all script mail must feature a 'from' address in the headers, which had to be a valid address associated with the hosting account.

Might be worth investigating that possibility.